# How to change parameters of Bert model for a better performance on test set?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, data-science, bert-language-model

I'm working on an NLP Task from Kaggle competition, the purpose is to predict if a tweet expresses a real disaster or not. I'm using BertForSequenceClassification.

My Training set size is 10000, I split it into:

- 8000 as Training set
- 2000 as Validation set
- Learning rate : 2e-5
- Epochs :4
- Batch size :32

Even if I have good learning curves, the performance on test set is bad (0.47 when submitting on Kaagle). I tried many changes on Learning rate and Epochs, but I still have the same problem.

How to change parameters of Bert model for a better performance on test set?

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification,AdamW,BertConfig
from transformers import BertTokenizer
print("Loading BertTokenizer...")
tokenizer=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")


model=BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-uncased",
    num_labels=2,
    output_attentions=False,
    output_hidden_states=False,
    
)

model.cuda()

optimizer=AdamW(model.parameters(),
                lr=1.5e-5,
                eps=1e-8,
               )

from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup

epochs=4

total_steps=len(train_dataloader)*epochs

scheduler=get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer,
                                          num_warmup_steps=0,
                                          num_training_steps=total_steps)


import random 

seed_val=42

random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

##################################################################
#                        TRAINING                                #
##################################################################     

# loss_values=[]

training_stats = []
for epoch_i in range(0,epochs):

  print("****Epoch {:} /{:} ******".format(epoch_i+1,epochs))
  print("Training...")

  t0=time.time()
  total_loss=0

  model.train()


  for step,batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    if step%100==0 and not step==0:
      elapsed=format_time(time.time()-t0)
      print(" Batch {:>5,} of {:>5,}. Elapsed: {:}".format(step,len(train_dataloader),elapsed))

    b_input_ids=batch[0].to(device)
    b_input_mask=batch[1].to(device)
    b_labels=batch[2].to(device)
   

    model.zero_grad()
    # outputs=model(b_input_ids,
    #               token_type_ids=None,
    #               # attention_masks=b_input_mask,
    #               labels=b_labels
    #               )
    
    loss, logits = model(b_input_ids,
                                  token_type_ids=None, 
                                  attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                                  labels=b_labels
                           )

  
    total_loss +=loss.item()
    loss.backward()

    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(model.parameters(),1.0)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()

  avg_train_loss=total_loss/len(train_dataloader)

  
  print("")
  print(" Average training loss :{0:.2f}".format(avg_train_loss))
  print("Training epoch took {:}".format(format_time(time.time()-t0)))
  training_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)



##################################################################
#                        VALIDATION                                #
##################################################################     

  print("")
  print("Runing Validation ...")

  t0=time.time()
  model.eval()

  total_eval_loss,eval_accuracy=0,0
  nb_eval_steps,nb_eval_examples=0,0

  for batch in validation_dataloader:

    batch=tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)

    b_input_ids,b_input_mask,b_labels=batch

    with torch.no_grad():
    #   outputs=model(b_input_ids,
    #                 token_type_ids=None,
    #                 # attention_masks=b_input_mask
    #                 )
    # logits=outputs[0]
      loss, logits = model(b_input_ids, 
                                token_type_ids=None, 
                                attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                                labels=b_labels)


      total_eval_loss += loss.item()
    #Move to cpu

    logits=logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
    label_ids=b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()


    # # Accuracy of this batch 
    tmp_eval_accuracy=flat_accuracy(logits,label_ids)
    eval_accuracy+=tmp_eval_accuracy
    nb_eval_steps+=1
    
  print("  Accuracy: {0:.2f}".format(eval_accuracy/nb_eval_steps)) 
  print("  Validation took:{:}".format(format_time(time.time()- t0)))
  avg_val_loss = total_eval_loss / len(validation_dataloader)
  print(" Average validation loss :{0:.2f}".format(avg_val_loss))

  avg_val_accuracy = eval_accuracy / len(validation_dataloader)
  validation_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)
  


  training_stats.append(
      {
          'epoch': epoch_i + 1,
          'Training Loss': avg_train_loss,
          'Valid. Loss': avg_val_loss,
          'Valid. Accur.': avg_val_accuracy,
          'Training Time': training_time,
          'Validation Time': validation_time
      }
  )

  
print("")   
print("Training completed!")
```

And I put results on  CSV to submit like this

```
predictions=predictions[:,1]
predictions[predictions>0]=0
predictions[predictions<0]=1
predictions=predictions.astype(np.int64)

sample_submission=pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv',sep=',',index_col=0)
sample_submission["target"]=predictions
sample_submission.head()

to_submit=sample_submission.to_csv("submission.csv",index=True)
```

[image: Learning curves]

Comment: You can make a loop to fit the on the different parameters, BUT you might end up overfitting on the test set... look around for what parameters and levels work better with your feature data types

Comment: Do you mean loop over leaning rate values,epochs,batch size,..? it'll take a long time !